# Solution of $u_{xy} = e^y$ should be dependent on $y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> For the hyperbolic equation $\; u_{xy} = e^y\;$ on the Cauchy curve $\; \Gamma : y(x) = 1 - \frac{x}3$
>
> $u(x,y)|_{\Gamma} = \frac12 - x\;$ ve $\; u_y(x,y)|_{\Gamma} = \sqrt{3-x}\;$ is given
>
> Find the value of the $u(x,y)$ solution at $(x_0, y_0) = (3, 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By partial integration, solutions are of the form
$$
u(x,y) = x e^y + f(x) + g(y) \, ,
$$
where $f$, $g$ are arbitrary functions.
The boundary $\Gamma$ is described by the equation $y=1−\frac{x}3$, or equivalently $x = 3(1-y)$. The boundary condition $u_y|_Γ=\sqrt{3-x}$ yields the differential equation $$g'(y)=\sqrt{3y}−3(1−y)e^y$$ which [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%27%28y%29+%3D+sqrt%283+y%29+-+3+%281-y%29+e%5Ey) reads
$$g(y) = \tfrac{2}{\sqrt 3} y^{3/2} + 3(y-2) e^y + c_1 \, .$$
You can find $f(x)$ by using $u|_Γ=\frac12−x$:
\begin{aligned}
f(x)|_\Gamma &= \big(\tfrac12−x - g(y) - xe^y\big)|_\Gamma \\
&= \tfrac12−x - \tfrac{2}{\sqrt 3} (1-\tfrac{x}3)^{3/2} + 3 e^{1-{x}/3} - c_1 \, .
\end{aligned}
The constant $c_1$ simplifies in the final expression of $u(3,1)=3e+f(3)+g(1)$.

Comment: @drstress in the expression of $g(y)$, the letter $y$ can replaced by whatever letter on both sides of the equation, as long as you tell the reader what you do. Please delete old comments